# Only allow one item to be checked in each line

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that contains 3 checkboxes. The user can create many lines in the GridView but they cannot tick the same checkbox in each row.

For example in the screen shot below from the datebase, the first line has `Approved1` checked and the second line has `Approved3` checked, which is fine:

[image]

But if I add another line in the GridView and check `Approved1` in the third line so it now looks like this, I want to alert the user so they have to change the checkbox:

[image]

I want to loop through each of these rows from the database and alert the user that they cannot select the same approved check box i.e. in this example you cannot have `Approved1` ticked twice.

```
    bool check1 = false;
    bool check2 = false;
    bool check3 = false;

DataSet ds1 = DataUtils.GetQuoteDetails((int.Parse(Request.QueryString["QuoteID"])), Company.Current.CompanyID);
     foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
          check1 = Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Approved1"]);
          check2 = Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Approved2"]);
          check3 = Convert.ToBoolean(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Approved3"]);
     }
```

I have the code looping through the database but I am not sure how to check if any of the approved fields have been ticked twice.

Comment: why not use radio buttons, thats their purpose

Comment: Radio buttons will work on a row rather than a column. He wants it to work on the column if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PradeepKumar yes the issue here is checking the columns in a  database, so it wouldn't matter if I was using checkboxes or radio buttons

Comment: I think it would be easy for you to do that via Javascript rather than on server-side code. Implementing on server side isn't bad or impossible though.

Comment: If you could share the aspx markup for the girdview columns, I may be able to suggest you some solution.

Comment: @PradeepKumar each column looks something like this `<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Approved1" HeaderText="Approved1"></asp:BoundColumn>`

Comment: OK then how do you show the checkboxes there?? It would create a simple label there which you can't turn checked/unchecked, isn't it?

Comment: @PradeepKumar there a a button that pops up the checkboxes. Each row is saved into the database and the values in the database are then displayed in the grid. I want to do the check on server-side

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
       try
        {
            List<DataRow> datarowcol = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x["Approved1"] == "1").ToList();
            if (datarowcol != null && datarowcol.Count > 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Your message to user");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Print your message -> ex.Message
        }
```

this will return datarow if any row have `Approved1` is equal to `"1"` else it will return null.

Not tested but it should work.

Note: Make sure namespace `using System.Linq` you have added.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @user123456789 similarly you can check for `Approved2` and `Approved3`.

Comment: this just returns all the rows. do I need to add something else? like if two rows have `Approved1` equal to 1 then throw `exception`

Comment: @user123456789 i modified my answer, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can go column by column and check for existence of rows with "Approved=1" value.

```
DataSet ds1 = DataUtils.GetQuoteDetails((int.Parse(Request.QueryString["QuoteID"])), Company.Current.CompanyID);
DataTable dt = ds1.Tables(0);
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
    switch (dc.ColumnName) {
        case "Approved1":
        case "Approved2":
        case "Approved3":   //-- add more column names here that you want to check
            DataRow[] approvedRows = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " = 1");
            if (approvedRows.Length > 1) {
                //-- this is the case you are looking for... this column has more than one rows selected
                //-- I am showng a messagebox.. you may do other custom handling here..
                string msg = string.Format("Column \"{0}\" has {1} selections, which is not allowed!", dc.ColumnName, approvedRows.Length);
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return; // we don't want to show any more messageboxes.
            }
            break;
    }
}
```